# Display ASP.NET VB User Control property in VS IDE

Tags: vb.net, ide, properties, visual-studio-2003, web-user-controls

I built a VB ASP.NET 1.1 Web User Control that contains several properties.  I want these properties to display in the VS2003 IDE Properties window, for easy manipulation.  However, none of the properties appear!  How do I make them show in the IDE?

I am a C# guy, and not very familiar with VB, so this is probably a no-brainer.  Here's a property, including attributes:

```
Private _priceHigh As String = "2000"
<Browsable(True), Category("SearchProperties"), Description("Foo"), DefaultValue("2000")> _ 
Public Property PriceHigh() As String
  Get
    Return _priceHigh
  End Get
  Set(ByVal Value As String)
    _Pricehigh = Value
  End Set
End Property
```

Comment: I still have not figured this out.  I think I remember this being a problem, having encountered it way back in 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute syntax is wrong.  It should look like this:

```
<Browsable(True)> _
<Category("SearchProperties")> _
<Description("Foo")> _
<DefaultValue("2000")> _
Public Property ....
```

Comment: I get compile errors when I do that, which is why I tried using commas.  I get the blue underline at the beginning of the second attribute.  This is .NET 1.1, if that makes any difference.  "Attribute specifier is not a complete statement.  Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the Following statement"

Comment: Are you sure you copied my underscores over?  That's what the error message is complaining about.

Comment: Did you add a space between the `>` and the underscore? They can't be adjacent.

Comment: I did that.  VS2003 compiler checks for that.  I also tried adding a space after the underscore, too.  I have never been able to get this to work in VB on VS2003, but C# works just fine...

Comment: I tried using only the Browsable attribute, to see if that will work.  NOPE!  perhaps it's simply an issue with VS2003 not being able to display VB properties in the IDE.  I seem to recall reading something about that many (many) years ago.